# mysql coupled OR statement

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-function

I'm trying to do a **coupled OR** statement

```
select * from table where cat = "x" OR (cat = "y" AND rand()<=0.25);
```

So I would like to select all items with cat = x or cat = y, but only 25% of y. The statement above gives med 25% of both x and y.

How can I seperate my statement so this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "but only 25% of y"?

Comment: You can not do this with ORs if cat="x" then it will not even try to look at Y. That gives u all Xs and quarter of Ys

Comment: Odd behavior.  Perhaps instead of OR use a union ?  I'd like to see this behavior in action in a sqlfiddle.com or rextest.com example.  as all of x should be returned adn only y if a random number is less than 25%  note: you're not guaranteed 25% of y.  all you're guaranteed is that if a random value between 0 and 1 is <=.25 you'll get that record.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing but i can almost smell that this is a very dodgy way to implement SQL.

I assume, you want to change your where clause if random number generates a result with %25 probability.You can not do this with ORs if cat="x" then it will not even try to look at Y. That gives u all Xs and quarter of Ys.

Try this for implementation of probablity check.

```
IF  (RAND() <= 0.25)  
     { sql_statement_forY  }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement_forX  } ]
```